# How to sum value of the same type with two level array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with two levels looking like this one:

```
let myArray = [
{
    "name": "Job 01",
    "isSelected": true,
    "Items": [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name": "Shopping",
            "quantity": 100
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name": "Walking",
            "quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name": "Singing",
            "quantity": 20
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Job 02",
    "isSelected": false,
    "Items": [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name": "Shopping",
            "quantity": 100
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name": "Walking",
            "quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name": "Singing",
            "quantity": 20
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Job 03",
    "isSelected": true,
    "Items": [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name": "Shopping",
            "quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name": "Singing",
            "quantity": 10
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Job 04",
    "isSelected": true,
    "Items": []
},
]
```

So I am trying to achieve a final array of something like.

```
let finalArray = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "Shopping",
        "quantity": 120
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "name": "Walking",
        "quantity": 20
    },
    {
        "id" : 5,
        "name": "Singing",
        "quantity": 30
    }
]
```

The final array iterate to sum the items only for jobs that has isSelected  = true. I know I can reduce method but I can't figure out how to use it when there are two levels of array in one object.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried to create a new jobs array for only that that is selected. like so  let jobs = [];

        for (i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
            let job = myArray[i];
            if (job.isSelected) {
                jobs.push(job);
            }
        }

Comment: Here is what I am stuck with:  let result = jobs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
           //Not sure how I could access the Items in each job here and add them up.
        }, []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of reduce & put loop on Items property to accumulate data based on id property:

```js
const myArray = [{"name":"Job 01","isSelected":true,"Items":[{"id":1,"name":"Shopping","quantity":100},{"id":3,"name":"Walking","quantity":20},{"id":5,"name":"Singing","quantity":20}]},{"name":"Job 02","isSelected":false,"Items":[{"id":1,"name":"Shopping","quantity":100},{"id":3,"name":"Walking","quantity":20},{"id":5,"name":"Singing","quantity":20}]},{"name":"Job 03","isSelected":true,"Items":[{"id":1,"name":"Shopping","quantity":20},{"id":5,"name":"Singing","quantity":10}]},{"name":"Job 04","isSelected":true,"Items":[]}];
const result = Object.values(myArray.reduce((acc, {isSelected, Items})=>{
     isSelected && Items.forEach(o=>{
         acc[o.id] ??= {...o, quantity:0};
         acc[o.id].quantity+=o.quantity;
    })
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me out. Object.values(myArray.reduce((acc, {isSelected, Items})

Answer (score 1):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myTransform = arr => (
  Object.values(
    arr.filter(
      ({ isSelected }) => isSelected
    ).flatMap(
      ({ Items }) => Items
    ).reduce(
      (acc, {id, name, quantity}) => {
        const k = `${id}${name}`;
        acc[k] ??= { id, name, quantity: 0};
        acc[k].quantity += quantity;
        return acc;
      },
      {}
    ) ?? {}
  )
);

/* explanation
// transform array to required/desired format
const myTransform = arr => (
  Object.values(    // extract only the values-array from intermediate result object
    arr?.filter(     // filter the input-array to keep only "isSelected" items
      ({ isSelected }) => isSelected
    )?.flatMap(      // ".flatMap" filtered array to extract only "Items" prop
      ({ Items }) => Items
    )?.reduce(       // reduce the "Items" array to create intermediate result object
      (acc, {id, name, quantity}) => {    // destructure to access id, name, qty
        const k = `${id}${name}`;         // "acc" key is combination of id & name
        acc[k] ??= { id, name, quantity: 0};    // if id-name not already present in "acc"
        acc[k].quantity += quantity;      // increment the quantity
        return acc;                       // always return accumulator "acc"
      },
      {}          // initialize "acc" as empty object
    ) ?? {}       // if "arr.filter().flatMap().reduce() is null/undefined, use empty object
  )
);
*/

let myArray = [{
    "name": "Job 01",
    "isSelected": true,
    "Items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Shopping",
        "quantity": 100
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Walking",
        "quantity": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Singing",
        "quantity": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Job 02",
    "isSelected": false,
    "Items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Shopping",
        "quantity": 100
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Walking",
        "quantity": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Singing",
        "quantity": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Job 03",
    "isSelected": true,
    "Items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Shopping",
        "quantity": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Singing",
        "quantity": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Job 04",
    "isSelected": true,
    "Items": []
  },
];

console.log('transformed array to:\n', myTransform(myArray));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.